# PC powers off after new Pure Rock be quiet CPU cooler installed

Tags: cpu, power-supply, cooling, overheating, heatsink

I decided to upgrade my PC as it was fairly noisy, this was due to the stock *CPU heatsink fan* and the *case fans*.

So I bought myself a *new case* and a **Pure Rock Be Quiet** heatsink.

Transferred my components across to my new case powered the PC up and it ran fine as expected, until I started playing games after about one minute into FIFA 17 locked at 60FPS the PC just **shuts down** without any warning.

I believed this to be an overheating issue so I fiddled around with everything, moved some things, refused to believe it could be my brand new cooler as the temps recorded from the CPU topped about **34C** when gaming and was the temperature when the PC would shut off.

I then replaced the new cooler with my old stock cooler and the PC now plays games fine without causing it to shut off, even though the CPU temp is now around **68C** when gaming.

My next thought was maybe the PSU? I have a 500 Watt PSU and using a PSU calculator with my components it appears to be enough to handle what it's running.

My specs are:

- AMD FX-8350
- (2x8GB) DDR3 1600MHz RAM
- Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3 Socket AM3+ 7.1 Channel Audio ATX Motherboard
- Coolermaster Elite Power 500W Fully Wired Efficient Power Supply
- Crucial 64GB M4 SSD - 2.5" SATA-III - Read 500MB/s Write 95MB/s
- 1 TB HHD
- EVGA Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti

I am at a bit of a loss to what could be causing the issue, the only difference between the *stock cooler* and the *new cooler* is that the stock cooler has a latch that you pull down once it's hocked onto the brackets around the processor which secures it in place, where as the new cooler just hooks onto the bracket and is just secured into place by tightening the screws on the bridge that hooks onto the bracket, maybe it's not fully connected onto the CPU even though it doesn't appear to have a gap between the heatsink and the processor and when you remove it the processor appears to be covered in the thermal paste from the heatsink which would suggest it's touching?

The only thing I can think of is the PSU? Or maybe the motherboard? any other suggestions or has anyone dealt with something similar?

Note, it's not just FIFA it does this, I ran the benchmarks for GTA V and got the same result.

Comment: So previously you got temps of 35C while gaming, now 68C while gaming? What changed.... that's a huge jump. Also, where are you reading it from?

Comment: As if that's the difference between the two coolers, I'd suggest that the new cooler wasn't seated properly.

Comment: well it started around 28c it would get up to 35c then turn off. The old stock cooler that came with my AMD processor would start off the same and then get up to as hot as 68c and be fine without turning off. The new cooler could probably get hotter but the PC turns off before it gets any hotter. I'm recording via a temp probe connected to an LED bay which is accurate to 2c and matches what is recorded by hwmonitor as well so I know both can't be wrong

Comment: When you changed the heatsink, did you properly clean all old thermal paste off the CPU and applied new thermal paste to the CPU casing? Note that cleaning off the old thermal paste is not optional!

Comment: I didn't? It didn't really appear to have much left on/was dry. Should I clean it and reapply some fresh paste?

Comment: Yup remove, clean, reapply. Also, is the fan connected to the same point as the previous one? You might have settings in bios to control the fan and it's turning off because it thinks the fan isn't running fast enough? (Quieter fans tend to run slower). I've had to disable the fan check on my system because the fan runs so slowly (800~rpm) and this causes the system to believe the fan has failed.

Comment: I will do that tonight then. Yeah it's plugged into the same point as the previous one. That's a fair point, I'll have a check in the bios and see if there is something for a fan check, thank you

Comment: @djsmiley2k got a feeling it could be the fan speed as you suggested, just checked and people are reporting speeds of around 6750 RPM on the stock fan: 
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1994244/8350-stock-fan-running-high-rpm.html
The Be Quiet fan max RPM is 1500. I'll check the BIOS settings out when I'm home and confirm this

Comment: I fixed this issue, in the end I had to update the BIOS and this fixed my issue and the aftermarket cooler began to work without causing my PC to shut off, @djsmiley2k I thank you for suggesting it was a fan check with the motherboard that was making it thinking the fan was malfunctioning and after the update the fan started to work so I suspect you were right, if you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess (that's all it is, an educated guess) is that the bios has a safety check for fan speed, and as this is a 'quiet' model, it's likely running a lot slower than the stock fan and so the bios may think the fan has failed.

I believe this, because the system shutting off at 36c seems odd (it's no where near overheating) but it maybe near the point at which the system would try and increase the speed of the fan. Something that wouldn't always happen with a slower fan setup.

I'd suggest checking in the bios for a fan speed alarm, and seeing if you can disable this (while keeping an eye on your fan and making sure it is working as expected). Sometimes it'll be configurable.

Sometimes there maybe a bios update that'll also help.